# Does it safe to save important keys on gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have some important keys in my application and I want to know where its the best place to put them. I also have enabled my proguard but when I decompile the app the keys steel visible, I was thinking put them on gradle.

Comment: The better way to do this is use NDK and write those keys in c file and the use JNI.

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Comment: See my answer and accept if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder jni(inside main) and create two files.

- hide_key.c.
- CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(hide_key SHARED
            hide_key.c)

# Include libraries needed for hide_key lib
target_link_libraries(hide_key
                      android
                      log)
```

Copy above and paste in CMakeLists.txt.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_/*replace with package*/_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                              jobject instance) {
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "key here");
}
```

This in hide_key.c.

Then in build.gradle

```
android{
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code do this to get the key.

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("hide_key");
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store those keys in the shared preference file with some encryption mechanism.